# Ignoring major version upgrades with "yarn up"?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I'm using Yarn 4. There are a few packages I'm keeping at older versions because the new versions are incompatible.

With Yarn 1's `yarn upgrade`, it ignored the major upgrades. With Yarn 2+, I think we're supposed to upgrade all packages with `yarn up '**'` or `yarn up -R '**'`. However, these also upgrade all the major versions.

With `yarn up`, seems like my options are:

1. `yarn up '**'`, then individually install the older versions
2. `yarn upgrade-interactive`, then press right + down a few dozen times

Is there another way to upgrade only the minor versions?

Comment: Could you use [resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#resolutions) to prevent an upgrade of the specifc packages?

Comment: Just tried resolutions, it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Did you try NCU?

Answer (score 1):

I guess `yarn up --caret --interactive` does what you want

However, both `yarn up` an `yarn upgrade-interactive` don't seem to be handy and easy to use, so I prefer using https://github.com/antfu/taze

```
$ taze minor --recursive --interactive

┃ ↑↓ to select, space to toggle, → to change version
┃ enter to confirm, esc to cancel

@me/project - 1 minor, 2 patch

❯ ◉ @types/node         dev          ~12d  ^20.10.6  →  ^20.11.0  ⩽1d
  ◉ @vitejs/plugin-vue  resolutions  ~12d    ^5.0.2  →    ^5.0.3  ~1d
  ◉ vite                resolutions  ~27d   ^5.0.10  →   ^5.0.11  ~6d
```

It will show what's it going to upgrade, then two presses of `Enter`, and it's installed.

By default, `taze` will only bump versions in the ranges you specified in `package.json` (which is safe and the default behavior of `npm install`)
In the above example I use `minor` that would break over `~` ranges and ignore majors